# How can I write the following C# code in a more precise and structured manner?

Tags: c#

This is a part of an online test. If I run the program in a compiler, the output is correct. And if I submit it for evaluation(test cases),I get the startindex error maybe because of unnecessary number of if - else conditions that I have used.

The program should return the time of the entered flight number.

```
public class Program   
{

    static Dictionary<string, DateTime> flightSchedule = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>(){
                                                    {"ZW346", Convert.ToDateTime("13:54:10")},
                                                    {"AT489", Convert.ToDateTime("16:30:00")},
                                                     {"BR267", Convert.ToDateTime("21:15:30")}};


    public static void Main(string[] args)   
    {
        string flight;
        Console.Write("Enter the Flight Number : ");
        flight=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(flightStatus(flight));

    }  

    public static string flightStatus(string flightNo) 
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if(flightNo=="ZW346")
        {
            if(now<flightSchedule["ZW346"])
            {
                TimeSpan ts = flightSchedule["ZW346"].Subtract(now);
                return "Time To Flight"+" "+ts.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "Flight Already Left";
            }
        }
        else if(flightNo=="AT489")
        {
            if(now<flightSchedule["AT489"])
            {
                TimeSpan tx = flightSchedule["AT489"].Subtract(now);
                return "Time To Flight"+" "+tx.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "Flight Already Left";
            }
        }
        else if(flightNo=="BR267")
        {
            if(now<flightSchedule["BR267"])
            {
                TimeSpan ty = flightSchedule["BR267"].Subtract(now);
                return "Time To Flight"+" "+ty.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "Flight Already Left";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Invalid Flight Number";
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, flagging for closing.

Comment: are you sure you are testing the right code? How do you test this? Is the bug in your UnitTest? Which line exactly produces the error?

Comment: Please provide the code for the test case that is failing.

Comment: Confirmed unable to reproduce error. Here is a [.NET Fiddle which functions as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/czArPt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do note that your code raises no error, so this answer adresses how to structure the code in a more reusable way.

```
    static Dictionary<string, DateTime> flightSchedule = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>()
    {
        {"ZW346", Convert.ToDateTime("13:54:10")},
        {"AT489", Convert.ToDateTime("16:30:00")},
        {"BR267", Convert.ToDateTime("21:15:30")}
    };
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string flight;
        Console.Write("Enter the Flight Number : ");
        flight = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(flightStatus(flight));

    }

    public static string flightStatus(string flightNo)
    {
        if (!flightSchedule.ContainsKey(flightNo))
        {
            return "Invalid Flight Number";
        }
        DateTime departureTime = flightSchedule[flightNo];
        if (DateTime.UtcNow < departureTime)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = departureTime.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
            return "Time To Flight" + " " + ts.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "Flight Already Left";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What date does this give? `Convert.ToDateTime("13:54:10")` It will always be in the past.

You should add a date. For example:

```
{"ZW346", new DateTime(
    DateTime.Now.Year, 
    DateTime.Now.Month, 
    DateTime.Now.Day, 13, 54 ,10)}
```

Comment: I am not supposed to change these values. It was already given.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I don't believe that a date is needed. One of the examples on the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) page passes just the time. Also, the code tests fine on [ideone](https://ideone.com/FBMaTe).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the question's code works fine indeed, that is the first thing I mention in my answer.

Comment: @bradbury9 I have mentioned that the code runs fine when I am using any other compiler. But when I tried to evaluate it to pass the test cases, it showed me the StartIndex error. Which I still can't figure out why.